# Java open source charts library with animation capabilities

Tags: java, charts, javafx

Is there any java library which is an opensource and also has the capabilities of animation .I know about JFreeChart but its charts are not that much attractive and secondly they also do not have animation feature.
      Secondly i do found javafx .Kindly give me an idea is it difficult to associate javafx charts with java code? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Charting and Reporting @ java-source.net](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting) and [15 useful Java Java Charting and Reporting Tools](http://blog.dreamcss.com/dev-tools/charts/java-charting-and-reporting-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to associate JavaFX charts with Java Code.  For example, the following Java code will create a JavaFX PieChart:

```
final PieChart chart = new PieChart(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
  new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
  new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
  new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30)
));
```

If you use the JavaFX charts, make sure you are using the newest JavaFX 2 code base (where the JavaFX code is written in Java) rather than the older JavaFX 1.3 code base (where the JavaFX code is written in a specialized script language).

JavaFX has a charting API and an animation API, but not a specific API for animating charts.  You can perform animation on chart elements using JavaFX, but you need to either write the API and code to perform the animation on the charts yourself or base your chart on JavaFX Ensemble sample (which is not a full animation API for charts).

To help determine whether JavaFX charting is a good match for your application, review the [JavaFX Samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html).  The Ensemble sample application has examples for both static and animated charts.  The SwingInterOp sample application has an example of embedding a JavaFX graph inside a traditional Java Swing application.  There is [good documentation on JavaFX charting](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm).

Note that JavaFX (as of 2.0.2) does not currently have a printing API, in case printed charts is also a consideration, though you could leverage the printing capabilities of Swing if needed.